# MySQL Convert Single Cell Value from Seconds to Time Format

Tags: mysql

This might be so simple but I am a MySQL newbie and have combed the documentation and cant figure out the correct syntax.  I have one cell (Wait) in "helpdesk_data" that gets updated from another table called "temp_data" (Column 4). The value is updating fine but the value is in seconds or an INT. I need to convert it to MINUTES and SECONDS to display correctly in the TIME format that I have designated for that Column type of the "Wait" Column.

```
UPDATE temp_data a, helpdesk_data b
SET b.Wait = a.`Column 4`
WHERE a.id = 2;
```

I've tried the  `SEC_TO_TIME(Seconds)` I understand the concept but how do I get the value of this cell to populate the (Seconds) input of the `SEC_TO_TIME` command and update the final value in the helpdesk_data table or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: _“but how do I get the value of this cell to populate the (Seconds) input of the SEC_TO_TIME command”_ – `SEC_TO_TIME(column_name_goes_here)` …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
UPDATE temp_data a, helpdesk_data b
SET b.Wait = SEC_TO_TIME(a.`Column 4`)
WHERE a.id = 2;
```

if your

```
a.`Column 4`
```

contains the seconds as integer values.